# how to adjust textview width based on images downloaded from internet

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I have a textview and a image view in linear layout with weight assigned. This linear layout is for list items. Problem is sometimes, the URL for image, is giving error, so Picasso library also returns to onError(). 
For such scenarios, I want that the text view shall occupy complete width instead of what is decided by its weight.

Layout snippet:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Picasso snippet in Adapter :

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mValues.get(position).getString("imageHref"))
    .into(holder.mImageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            holder.mContentView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            try {
                 holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).getString("description"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```

This doesn't seems to work as the callback comes after some delay, and my textView is already updated with some value for textView width according to layout weight.

Comment: Set textview width to "fill_parent" and hide the imageview in onError() handler.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set visibility `GONE` when `error`:

```
@Override
public void onError() {
  mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  [...]
}
```

If it is `ListView` row then you must set `VISIBLE` when `success`:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
  mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the visibility of the ImageView to gone by default, so that the image is not shown and the TextView gets all the space. Only if loading the image has succeeded, set the visibility of the ImageView to visible.

Or you can also do it the other way round and set visibility to gone if loading the image returns an error. This would be better approach if you plan on showing some loading-indicator image while the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `textView` params like below :

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```